# Eclipse error for Double

Tags: java, eclipse

I have this error when I try to compile it in Eclipse, but When I try to compile it using Command line (javac) then it works.

```
double y = new Double(1) / 2;

System.out.println(y);
```

"The operator / is undefined for the argument type(s) Double, int"

Can someone also explain to me what does new Double(1) actually do? Thank very much.

Comment: tried in eclipse. working fine.

Comment: Hmm weird, it's not working for me. :O

Comment: What version of eclipse you're  using?

Comment: Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

Version: Kepler Service Release 1
Build id: 20130919-0819

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question that you asked is what does `new Double(1)` do?  The answer to that is that it creates a `Double` object that represents that value 1.

Probably what you want to do in this case is really

```
 double y = ((double) 1) / 2;
```

That will cast the value 1 to the type `double` (rather than creating an object of class `Double`) and let this calculation proceed.  Alternatively, you could make one or both of the constants explicitly floating point like this:

```
 double y = 1.0 / 2.0;
```

I personally prefer this last option, but it's a matter of preference.

As for why you got the error - Could it be different versions of Java being used.  For that expression to work, you need auto-unboxing.  An older compiler won't support that.

Comment: Brick, your answer is correct -- autoboxing is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Because the expression uses an operator that mixes the Double (uppercase) object and the double (lowercase) primitive, the correct interpretation relies on [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html), which was introduced in Java 1.5

The expression is valid when using any compiler that is configured for language compatibility version 1.5 or greater.

It's likely that you have a setting in eclipse that has your java compiler set to version 1.4 or older.   Check the compiler settings for the project.